# Qt Designer promoted widget layout

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, qt-designer

I am using Qt Designer for designing my user interfaces, and I want to build custom widgets which could be a combination of existing qt widgets such as a QLabel and QPushButton attached screenshot

[image].

Now I would like this to be independent with it's own business logic, signals and slots in a separate python file, but would want to add this as a component to my main screen.

I tried above by creating seprate ui file of type widget, but when I promote that from my MainWindow, it won't show up, and the code generated by pyuic would add it to the layout, but it is not rendered in main window.

[image]

Is there a way of doing that in PyQt and QDesigner?

**EDIT**:

Here is the actual code:

*timer.py*:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

from logbook import info


import timer_ui


class Timer(QtGui.QWidget, timer_ui.Ui_TimerWidget):

    start_time = None
    running = False
    total_time = 0
    time_spent = ''

    activity = None

    stopwatch = 0
    elapsed_time = None
    total_elapsed_time = timedelta()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(parent) #for custom widget parent is main window here which is dashboard

        self.lcdNumber.setDigitCount(12)

        self.qt_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.qt_timer.timeout.connect(self.timer_event)
        self.qt_timer.start(1000)

        self.goButton.clicked.connect(self.go)
        self.breakButton.clicked.connect(self.break_timer)

    def go(self):
        # date text format .strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
        self.start_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        self.running = True




        self.goButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.breakButton.setEnabled(True)

    def break_timer(self):
        ''' break finishes the activity '''
        break_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        self.activity.log_break(break_time.isoformat())
        self.activity = None  # activity completed

        self.total_elapsed_time += self.elapsed_time
        info(self.total_elapsed_time)

        self.running = False


        # self.lcdNumber.display(str(self.timer.get_elapsed()))

        self.goButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.breakButton.setEnabled(False)


    def timer_event(self):
        '''Updates the widget every second'''

        if self.running == True:
            current_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

            # if self.elapsed_time is None:

            self.elapsed_time = current_time - self.start_time
            # else:
            #self.elapsed_time += current_time - self.timer.start_time.replace(microsecond=0)
            if self.total_elapsed_time is not None:
                 self.lcdNumber.display(str(self.elapsed_time + self.total_elapsed_time))
            else:
                self.lcdNumber.display(str(self.elapsed_time))
```

*mainwindow.py*:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'dashboard.ui'
#
# Created: Sat Mar 19 11:40:35 2016
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(772, 421)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.widget = Timer(self.centralwidget)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.userNameLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.userNameLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("userNameLabel"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.userNameLabel)
        self.logoutButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.logoutButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.logoutButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("logoutButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.logoutButton)

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listView)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 772, 23))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Title", None))
        self.userNameLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "You are now logged in as", None))
        self.logoutButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Logout", None))

from timer import Timer
```

*timer_ui.py*:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'timer.ui'
#
# Created: Sat Mar 19 11:41:40 2016
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_TimerWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, TimerWidget):
        TimerWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("TimerWidget"))
        TimerWidget.resize(412, 52)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(TimerWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(TimerWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lcdNumber = QtGui.QLCDNumber(TimerWidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.lcdNumber.setNumDigits(12)
        self.lcdNumber.setSegmentStyle(QtGui.QLCDNumber.Flat)
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lcdNumber)
        self.goButton = QtGui.QPushButton(TimerWidget)
        self.goButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("goButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.goButton)
        self.breakButton = QtGui.QPushButton(TimerWidget)
        self.breakButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("breakButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.breakButton)

        self.retranslateUi(TimerWidget)
        #QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TimerWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, TimerWidget):
        #TimerWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("TimerWidget", "Form", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("TimerWidget", "Total hours spent", None))
        self.goButton.setText(_translate("TimerWidget", "Go!", None))
        self.breakButton.setText(_translate("TimerWidget", "Break", None))
```

Answer (score 1):

Promoted widgets are just placeholders for standard Qt widgets. You cannot create a custom widget for Qt Designer that way.

It can be done, but the process is much more complicated than simple widget promotion. See [Writing Qt Designer Plugins](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#writing-qt-designer-plugins) in the PyQt docs, and for a detailed tutorial, see [Using Python Custom Widgets In Qt Designer](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Using_Python_Custom_Widgets_in_Qt_Designer) on the Python Wiki. The [PyQt source code](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) also has many more examples (look in *examples/designer/plugins*).

**EDIT**:

There are two problems with your code. Firstly, you are passing the wrong argument to `setupUi` in the `Timer` class. You should fix it like this:

```
class Timer(QtGui.QWidget, timer_ui.Ui_TimerWidget):
    ...
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Timer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) # pass in self, not parent
```

Secondly, you edited the *mainwindow.py* file and broke one of the layouts. Never, ***ever*** edit the modules generated by `pyuic`! The line you broke is this one:

```
        # self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
```

But don't try to fix this by editing - instead, make sure you *regenerate* all the ui modules with `pyuic` so you get back to clean, unedited files again.

Comment: I don't want to render it in qt designer, but only promote it which I am able to now. But my custom widget which is a composite of standard widget needs to be rendered when my app is compiled in same location as my placeholder.

Comment: @AftabNaveed. Well, you need to post some actual code, then. Images from Qt Designer are no use at all for debugging.

Comment: timer_ui generated by QtDesigner http://pastebin.com/XeDaFjk8  my wrapper around that ui is here  http://pastebin.com/GwwLTpP9 and finally the MainWindow is here http://pastebin.com/fDK9yiLd   

MainWindow is parent of placeholder, and place holder is timer.py which wraps around the Widget Generated by QtDesigner. That works fine, but I am not able to align it properly.

Comment: @AftabNaveed. I have added the code to your question. See the edit to my answer for how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time, i.e build Custom widgets and use them inside my main window.

I don't know what is the top level widget for your custom widget, but it should preferably be `QWidget` or `QFrame` from the list of `Containers` in the Qt Designer and add the child widgets inside it, let's name this custom widget file as `custom.ui`.

Next, create a Python class as follows:

```
Form, Base = uic.loadUiType('/path/to/custom.ui') # this path should be a relative path. For testing you can use absolute path.
class CustomWidget(Form, Base):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

You can add any number of signals and slots for the custom logic to the above class.

Similarly create a class for your main window and then create an object of `CustomWidget` inside that main class and add that object to the layout.

```
Form2, Base2 = uic.loadUiType('/path/to/dashboard.ui') # this path should be a relative path. For testing you can use absolute path.
class Window(Form2, Base2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.cWidget = CustomWidget(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cWidget)
```

**Note:** This code is compatible with Python 2.x, if you are using Python 3.x, make necessary changes. This code is not tested, so syntax errors must also be resolved if found.